# Resizing videoJS, container resized, but actual vid still original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video.js

I am resizing my videojs player on `window.resize`

The black "video container", if you will, gets resized, but the actual video, stays the same size. It will now shrink inside its container (resized), or overlap its container (resized to smaller).

A page reload rebuilds the player and it plays within its new bounds.

How do I tell it to re-initialize on the new size, without a page reload.

What makes this extra interesting, is that it seems to work when running on my localhost, development web-server. Running it on on-line hosting, renders above issues.

```
function redrawVideoPlayer() {

    var newHeight
    var newWidth
    newWidth = $(window).width() * 0.33;
    newHeight = newWidth * 0.75;

    $('#ytvidplayer').css('height', newHeight);

    $('#ytvidplayer').css('width', newWidth);

    //set related video div height eual to video height

    $('#related_vids_scroller').css('height', newHeight);

    var myVideo = videojs('ytvidplayer');
    myVideo.width(newWidth).height(newHeight);
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing a cacheing issue when you view this online? Since this is all client side, there should be zero difference between localhost and other environments.

Comment: @MattMcClure, I had interesting issues relating to chrome and its event handling with window.load, and document.ready recently. In that case, Chrome behaved differently on localhost. I am suspecting something like this as, here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a cool way to maintain your video's aspect ratio even after resizing events. Let's break it down:

1. You'll need a resize function that takes in the known aspect ratio of your video (in my code it is the 'dimensionsize' parameter passed into a resizeVideoJS() function as a string like so: '1920x760'. The other parameters are the initialized videoJS video object 'video' and the browser window object 'win'.) I'm passing in parameters because my code is broken into two modules, one module that handles action and helper functions - like resizeVideo or togglePoster, etc. - and the other is a widget that initializes and binds events to the video object. The resizeVideoJS() function is defined in the actions module and called in the widget.

So here is the code:

```js
function resizeVideoJS( video, win, dimensionSize ) {

    var width,
 aspectRatio;

    video.pause();
    aspectRatio = _calculateAspectratio( dimensionSize );
    width = video.width() <= 0 ? win.innerWidth : video.width();
    video.height( width * aspectRatio );
}

function _calculateAspectratio( videoDimensionsStr ) {
 
    var parts;
    parts = videoDimensionsStr.split( 'x' );
    return parts[ 1 ] / parts[ 0 ];
}
```

2. Next, I simply create a _resizeCallbackHelper() function in my widget that checks against resize events and fires off whenever they occur (although I also use Lodash's throttle function with it because resize events can fire off rapidly).

```js
function _resizeCallbackHelper( ) {

  if ( config[ screensize ].dimensions && win.innerWidth !== screen.windowWidth ) {
    videoPoster ? dom.hide( videoPoster ) : false;
    screen = videoAction.setScreenSizeInfoVariables( win );
    _setVideoDimensions();
    videoAction.resizeVideoJS( video, win, dimensionSize );
    config[ screensize ].poster ? _setVideoPoster() : false;
  }
}
```

A little explanation about the above _resizeCallbackHelper() function:

config[screensize] is a configuration object I create from data-settings="" inside the video tag in my html. This has all the settings of the video, like video.muted() or even video.dimensions.  I made this as an object of nested objects, so that it looks like { Desktop: { dimensions: '1920x760', muted: true }, Mobile : { dimensions: '760x320', muted: false } }.  But you can do it however you want.  I just like this because it allows for custom settings across different devices.  I define my dimensions and screensize using the below _setVideoDimensions() function where screen is an object with booleans telling which screen type the video is loading in.  As you can see config[screensize] becomes either config['MOBILE'] or config['TABLET'] or config['DESKTOP'] in order to load those settings:

```js
function _setVideoDimensions() {
  
  screensize = screen.isHandheld ? ( screen.isMobile || screen.isLargeMobileDevice ? 'MOBILE' : 'TABLET' ) : 'DESKTOP';
  dimensionSize = config[ screensize ].dimensions || desktop.dimensions;
}
```

The 'win.innerWidth !== screen.windowWidth' in the resize helper function is a check against resize events that fire in tablets when scrolling, even though the screen does not actually resize.  This is a good thing to understand and know happens when scrolling in most tablets. Then I fire off some events that need to happen on resize, including the resizeVideoJS() function from the videoAction module - and notice I make sure to set the new video dimensions first with _setVideoDimensions().

3. Finally, I make sure to call the resize helper function on the resize event like so:

```js
resizeCallback = throttle( _resizeCallbackHelper, 2000 );

$.on( 'window', 'resize', resizeCallback );
```

I hope this helps anyone coming across this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This issue is long gone out of my life, so I won't be able to test your answer. Hopefully it helps someone else out in the future, and then we can mark it as solved. Thanks.